# Visual Studio: Macro definition of snprintf conflict

Tags: c++, visual-studio, printf

I am trying to compile some very old code, using visual studio 2017. When i build it, I get the following:

```
     Error  C1189   #error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration
  (compiling source file ordeviceinput_device.cxx)  ordeviceinput   
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\stdio.h
```

This, according to google, is because the definition of `snprintf` has been added to visual studio since this code was written (in 2008). The problem is, I can't find the definition in the code anywhere. There are many many headers included, and I cannot search through them all.

Is there a way around this?

Or do I need to build in an older version of VS?

Comment: A recursive directory search in VS should be able to find it quickly. Doesn't it?

Comment: *he problem is, I can't find the definition in the code anywhere. There are many many headers included, and I cannot search through them all.* -- Time to get a better tagging  utility to look up names.

Comment: `recursive directory search in VS` Is this a function that exists? Or do I need to write it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio 14+ defines `snprintf` to `_snprintf` in `stdio.h`.

Your code (or 3rd-party code you include) probably also defines it in the same way, hence it doesn't work.

Search for a line like this:

```
#define snprintf _snprintf
```

And change it to:

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1900
#  define snprintf _snprintf
#endif
```

**How to search in Visual Studio:**

- Edit -> Find and replace -> Search in Files... (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
- Find what:
   `#\s*define\s+snprintf`
- Look in:
  *Entire Solution ( Including External Items )*
- Match case
- Use Regular Expressions
- Find All...

Comment: Found it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is correct but root cause is
Visual Studio before version 14 doesn't provide snprintf, so we make do with _snprintf, which is non-conformant.